# VPN usage with 2 x SBS 2008 servers

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2008

I have an SBS 2008 server which we hope to connect with our other company office via VPN. The other office has it's own domain (different company) and uses its own SBS 2008 server.

Given that MS has restrictions as to the number of SBS 2008 servers in a network... will this pose any problems for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem whatsoever, as long as you're going to keep them 2 separate domains (no trusts, no shared authentication, no fancy Exchange setups). You are allowed to setup DNS forwarding, which could have some useful purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions to the number of SBS servers on a network. However, you should only ever have one SBS server per domain. Which basically means that you will need to set them up on two separate domains (eg. "my.company.com" and "my.office.com"). However, this will then end up in a situation where you also have two separate instances of Active Directory and people will need to remember different sets of passwords to log on to the different services.
This could get really messy over time. I would suggest that if you can afford it, you look at offering the services from of the SBS servers in a different way (normal Windows servers, Linux boxes, etc.)